# Kendo-UI and Angularjs Multiselect selections disappear

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm using Angularjs and Kendo-UI. When I use the Kendo-ui multiselect and I have other elements like  on the same view, the selections I have made in the multi-select list disappear when I type text into the .

I added a simple plunker demo at the link below. To use it, just select one or more states from the multi-select States list FIRST before entering an text in the textboxes. After selecting the states from the list, then enter text into the text boxes and the selected States just disappear from the multi-select list.

http://plnkr.co/edit/StiCOoTT4jzpfCwTOEVe?p=info

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the "k-" from the "k-ng-model" in the select element.
Here's a working version: http://plnkr.co/edit/hivBnyTyYtYHxDLJgF0i?p=preview

Comment: @yccteam nice way, do you know how I can make it rtl?

Comment: @eFarzad - is this link helpful: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/right-to-left-support?

Comment: @yccteam thank you, using class="k-rtl" in upper div, solved my problem