# Kendo UI and AngularJS Multiselect: Difference between ng-model and k-ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have two Kendo multi-select widgets in my template. The first one is like so:

```
<select kendo-multi-select="" 
        k-option-label="'Select Programs...'" 
        k-data-text-field="'name'" 
        k-data-value-field="'id'"  
        k-data-source="programs" 
        k-ng-model="selectedPrograms" 
        k-on-change="change(kendoEvent)">
</select>
```

The second one is like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="program in userData.programs">

    <select kendo-multi-select="" 
            k-option-label="'Select Services...'" 
            k-data-text-field="'name'" 
            k-data-value-field="'id'" 
            k-data-source="services" 
            ng-model="program.selectedServices" 
            k-on-change="change(kendoEvent)">
    </select>

</div>
```

Now here is my problem. Initially when I used the attribute to set `k-ng-model` in both multi-selects, the initial options that I had set in my controller would disappear on clicking the multi-select. This was the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894306/kendo-ui-and-angularjs-multiselect-selections-disappear). But as the solution there says, I removed the `k-ng-model` and replaced it with `ng-model`, and the second multi-select works perfectly.

But when I remove the `k-ng-model` and replace it with `ng-model` in my first multi-select, there is no pre-populated data. If I keep the `k-ng-model` it shows the pre-populated values, but on clicking the multi-select, they disappear.

What's happening here and how do I fix it?

Comment: What are the datasources?  Kendo.dataSource?  Also I cannot tell how your scopes are set up, but I have an inkling that if you were to put `selectedPrograms` in an object link `obj.selectedPrograms` that may solve your problem.

Comment: @CorySilva No, just regular objects returned from a GET request.

Answer (score 2):

ng-model provide only value and you can bind that value to your scope.

For example if you you are using datepicker control of Kendo then it will get you only date value for you like **"7/4/2016".**

whereas,

k-ng-model provide you complete value as object and you can bind it to your scope.

For example if you are using datepicker control of Kendo then it will get you complete date value for you as object like **"2016-07-12T05:00:00.000Z"**

You can also refer to this link on Kendo Website
@http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI developer here, we have done a lot of back and forth with AngularJS, ng-model, k-ng-model and the multiselect component recently. It would help if you can isolate the problem in a jsbin. Please make sure that you are using the latest version from the [repository](http://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/), too.

Comment: when to use k-ng-model vs. ng-model?